# After a multiple file ajax upload solution that ideally has examples for ASP.NET MVC if there's a server side component

Tags: jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc, image

Wish to upload multiple image files at the same time, with or without preview is fine. Just need an easy hassle free way to throw a lot of images at the server without browsing for each one, so a drag and drop input field would be ideal. Any extras like cropping prior to save commit would be a bonus.

Also if using preview prior to save/commit is it possible to generate the preview thumbs with javascript without having to send the image to server for resizing first? So throw multiple images
on the screen, get preview of them without making an ajax call to the server and only once you press save all of them will start uploading?

Answer (score 0):

A colleague of mine wrote an article about the basics of this earlier:

[Uploading files with HTML5, canvas and file api in a mvc3 application](http://www.novanet.no/blog/yngve-bakken-nilsen/dates/2012/2/uploading-files-with-html5-canvas-and-file-api-in-an-mvc3-application/)

Answer (score 0):

you can use [HTML5 FILE API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Using_files_from_web_applications#Example%3a_Showing_thumbnails_of_user-selected_images) to get the preview of images to be uploaded using javascript.

And you can select multiple images at once before uploading.

Hope this helps.